# (gitlab-runner) Docker finishes after 0 seconds

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

This is the log.

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.0.1 (xxx)
  on x-runner xxx
Preparing the "docker" executor
Job succeeded
```

The `Job succeeded` message comes after 0 seconds after the `Preparing the "docker" executor` message.

The scripts is `echo hello` and `npm ci`

---

**Update**: When I do `docker exec -it gitlab-runner gitlab-runner --debug run`, I get the error `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` after starting a pipeline. How do I fix this?

---

**Update**:

Versions

```
gitlab: 12.9.0
gitlab-runner: 13.0.1
docker: 19.03.11, build 42e35e61f3
```

Config

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "nuc-runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.x.y/"
  token = "xyz"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
```

---

**Update**:

.gitlab-cli.yml

```
# see https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html for all available options

stages:
  - install
  - build
  - test
  - clean

build:
  stage: build
  script: npm run build

install:
  stage: install
  script: npm ci

test:
  stage: test
  script: npm run test

clean:
  stage: clean
  script: npm run clean
```

---

**Update**

When I type

```
root@xxxxxxxxxxxx:/# gitlab-runner status
```

Stdout

```
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=365 revision=21cb397c version=13.0.1
gitlab-runner: Service is not running.
```

Comment: I doubt that there is anything wrong with the script, but believe that the runner may not be configured correctly. Could you update the question with the gitlab and runner version you're using + config?

Comment: I've updated the post.

Comment: please upload your `.gitlab.yml` file

Comment: I've updated the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out to not be the config in any way that caused the error. I didn't install the runner correctly. Another error was gitlab-runner service not starting as mentioned [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/3344) that was caused by installing gitlab-runner via apt.

How to solve installed with apt problem.

```
$ sudo su
root:~# cd /var/lib
root:/var/lib# mkdir gitlab-runner
root:/var/lib# chown gitlab-runner:gitlab-runner gitlab-runner/
root:/var/lib# service gitlab-runner restart
```

How to solve not installed correctly problem.

```
$ gitlab-runner install -u root
$ sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an `image` definition in any of the stages. Without that, I don't think there's anything for the docker executor to do. I'm only used to seeing the script section listed as an array, not sure if the string value is also valid. The result, if you want to use the `node:lts` image to run these, would look like:

```
stages:
  - install
  - build
  - test
  - clean

build:
  stage: build
  image: node:lts
  script:
  - npm run build

install:
  stage: install
  image: node:lts
  script:
  - npm ci

test:
  stage: test
  image: node:lts
  script:
  - npm run test

clean:
  stage: clean
  image: node:lts
  script:
  - npm run clean
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to do anything... I took your file and pasted it commited but it still finishes after 0 seconds.